# How can I skip a JSON Decode error when retrieving info from an API?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, api

I am filling out a data frame based on information from a website. I am importing the data via an API in a certain format, however, I am looking up the information based on an ID.Not every ID will be present in the lookup of the API. When it reaches an ID to search that isn't there the whole code breaks down.

The error is JSON Decode error. If I come across this, how can i catch the decode error and skip it so that it does not store any info about that ID and continues on?

```
endpoint = "generic website"
api_record_url = 'generic website'
api_key = '(deliberatelyhidden)'

def get_info_from_trove(title):
  params = {
      'q': str(title), 
      'zone': 'book', # Search in the newspaper zone
      'key': api_key,
      'encoding':'json'
     }

  response = requests.get(endpoint, params=params).json()
  #print("Fetching detail for ISBN:"+str(isbn))
  #print(response)
  try:
    print(response['response']['zone'][0]['records']['work'])
    if (len(response['response']['zone'][0]['records']['work'])>0):

      work_id = response['response']['zone'][0]['records']['work'][0]['id']
      print(work_id)
      params2 = {
                
          'include' : 'tags=comments,workversions',
          'reclevel' : 'full',
          'key': api_key,
          'encoding':'json'

        }
    # This sends our request to the Trove API and stores the result in a variable called 'response'
      response2 = requests.get(api_record_url + work_id + '?', params=params2)
      result = response2.json()
      for book in result:
        return('{} | {} | {}'.format(result['work']['version'][0]['record']['identifier'][0]['value'], result['work']['version'][0]['record']['title'],result['work']['version'][0]['record']['subject'] ))

      
  except:
    return('{} | {} | {}'.format(nan, nan, nan))
```

The function then gets processed here

```
books_to_search_trove = [titles]
info_trove = []
for isbn in books_to_search_trove:
  info_trove.append(get_info_from_trove(isbn))

ls = []
for line in info_trove:
      Type = line.split("|")
      ISBN = Type[0]
      Title = Type[1]
      Subject = Type[2]
      ls.append(Type)
print(ls)

cols = ['ISBN', 'Title', 'Subject']
trovedata = pd.DataFrame(ls, columns = cols)
print(trovedata)
trovedata.info()
```

Here is the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py in json(self, **kwargs)
    970         try:
--> 971             return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
    972         except JSONDecodeError as e:

5 frames
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py in json(self, **kwargs)
    973             # Catch JSON-related errors and raise as requests.JSONDecodeError
    974             # This aliases json.JSONDecodeError and simplejson.JSONDecodeError
--> 975             raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
    976 
    977     @property

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: python has `try/except` to catch errors. And you run first `get(...).json()` before `try` - use it inside `try/except`

Comment: I don't understand why you convert to string, next return string, and next convert it back to elements. You can directly return tuple or list `return ["nan", "nan", "nan"]`

Comment: `return` will exit `for`-loop on first item. If you have more results in JSON then you should first get all values and later use `return` with all values.

Comment: you run loop `for isbn ...` and next `for line ...` but you could do all in one `for`-loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have two `.json()` and first is before `try/except` but it should be also inside `try/except` - and this should help.

---

You could also make few changes to make code shorter

- in function there is no need to convert values to one `string` with `|` and later split it back. You can `return` `tuple` or `list`.
- you can run loop `for isbn ...` and `for line ...` as one loop without extra lists.

```
def get_info_from_trove(title):
    params1 = {
        'q': title,   # no need to convert string into string
        'zone': 'book', # Search in the newspaper zone
        'key': api_key,
        'encoding':'json'
    }

    params2 = {
        'include': 'tags=comments,workversions',
        'reclevel': 'full',
        'key': api_key,
        'encoding':'json'
    }

    try:
        #print("Fetching detail for:", title)
        
        response1 = requests.get(endpoint, params=params1)
        data1 = response1.json()
        #print('data1:', data1)
        
        work = data1['response']['zone'][0]['records']['work']
        print('work:', work)
        
        if work:

            work_id = work[0]['id']
            print('work_id:', work_id)
            
            response2 = requests.get(api_record_url + work_id, params=params2)
            data2 = response2.json()
            #print('data2:', data2)
            
            record = data2['work']['version'][0]['record']
            return (
                record['identifier'][0]['value'],
                record['title'],
                record['subject']
            )

    except:
        return ('nan', 'nan', 'nan')

# --- main ---

cols = ['ISBN', 'Title', 'Subject']
rows = []

for isbn in [titles]
     line = get_info_from_trove(isbn)
     rows.append(line)
     
print(rows)

trovedata = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=cols)

print(trovedata)
trovedata.info()
```